# Implementing undo/redo

Tags: c#, .net, performance, undo-redo

In a drawing application, I'm implementing multi-level undo/redo using [Memento pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern%E2%80%8E). One problem that I was facing was that the memento (the state object) would become too large if the drawing contains one or more image objects (my drawing object can have base64-encoded image objects embedded in it, just like Visual Studio's resx files), which would make the undo/redo stacks to climb to several megabytes soon because of the frequent mouse operations that are common in drawing apps. To solve this problem, I introduced gzip compression into it so that I now saved a zipped version of the memento onto the stack. This resulted in about 90% reduction in the overall stack size.

Now this has resulted in another problem. The time it takes to zip / unzip a memento has introduced considerable jags in object positioning/resizing.

One way to solve this is to use [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern), but I'm reluctant to go that path becuz it will introduce a whole lot of work in many parts of the application. What other alternates do you see?

Comment: You could only compress mementos older than X, or keep the last Y mementos always uncompress and compress them later as the stack grows. That way, you can always undo the last Y commands quickly, but still compress most of the history to save space.

Comment: @Poke This is a very interesting idea, but how would you handle the case where the stack has more than Y mementos? every operation will again require the compression of a new object.

Comment: @poke: As Samy points out, this ends up in the same place as I currently am at, only after Y mementos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I can think of without switching entirely to the Command pattern is to generate a kind of [incremental backup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_backup) of the object as a memento instead of using the whole object.

The idea is that you would strip from the memento any data that haven't changed. You would then only store the difference.

When doing an undo, you would use the current state of the object and the difference to generate a memento and inject it in the process.

Here's basically how it will look like:

1. *The caretaker is going to do something to the originator, but wants to be able to undo the change.*
2. *The caretaker first asks the originator for a memento object.*
3. *Then it does whatever operation (or sequence of operations) it was going to do.*
4. **A compressor will compare the memento and the new state of the originator and generate a diff object which will be stored on the operation stack**

To undo:

1. **The compressor will recreate a memento object from the originator state and the diff object**
2. *The new memento is then used to restore the originator state.*

The implementation of the compressor class might be tricky and will depend on the type of operations you will perform.

You will be using one single memento object and store only the diff objects which can also be compressed if needed but will probably be rather small.

Comment: Now this appears to be a very good idea. My mementos are strings (serialized object graph in xml), so if I could compute the "diff" of current and previous state, I could store that as memento. The problem now is how to compute "diff". I went thru several questions regarding that, but it seems like all of them handle strings on line-by-line basis instead of char-by-char which I need.

Comment: Finding the difference between two string is a well known algorithmic problem and many solution can be found. An edit distance is a metric that computes the difference between two strings (char by char), the Levenshtein's distance and LCS(longest common subsequence) are such edit distance and can be adapted to return the difference between two strings.

Comment: May I also say that you don't need the best solution but a good approximation. You can split your long string into chunks and compare them as if they were lines. Since you have an XML representation, you could also looks for tree comparison algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

When I did something similar in Delphi way back in the 90s I took snapshots, i.e. bitmaps of the current state, whenever the redraw got too slow, after lots of draw actions on the stack/queue/list. Not sure if you can do that, though.

Comment: Ah no, that is not an option for me. This is more of a vector-drawing app.